# How to import json file in ionic2

Tags: json, import, ionic2

I want to import a json file in my Ionic2 project. In my home.ts file I have

```
import * as data from '../../assets/i18n/en.json';
```

In my declarations.d.ts in the src folder, I have:

```
declare module '*.json' {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
declare module '*';
```

When I do "ionic serve" I got the following error and page does not load in the browser.

```
C:\Users\cju\Documents\Projects\Bus-DriverApp-Tabs>ionic serve

> ionic-hello-world@ ionic:serve C:\Users\cju\Documents\Projects\Bus-DriverApp-Tabs
> ionic-app-scripts serve

[14:20:18]  ionic-app-scripts 0.0.45
[14:20:18]  watch started ...
[14:20:18]  build dev started ...
[14:20:18]  clean started ...
[14:20:18]  clean finished in 5 ms
[14:20:18]  copy started ...
[14:20:18]  transpile started ...
[14:20:22]  build dev failed: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
[14:20:22]  copy finished in 4.45 s
[14:20:23]  watch ready in 4.48 s
[14:20:23]  dev server running: http://localhost:8100/
```

Here is my ionic info.

```
C:\Users\ccc\Documents\Projects\Bus-DriverApp-Tabs>ionic info

Your system information:

ordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.3 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.8 
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.4 
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.45 
ios-deploy version: Not installed 
ios-sim version: Not installed 
OS: Windows 7 Node Version: v6.9.1 
Xcode version: Not installed
```

I have google searched around, but could not solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Create your localization files in www/assets/i18n/:
www/assets/i18n/es.json

JSON file should look like this:
{
    "key" : "Translation for Key",
    "nested": {
        "user": "User",
        "signIn": "Sign In",
        "signUp": "Sign Up"
    }
}

app.ts and setup the required configuration. First of all the required imports.
Now add provider and pipe to ionicBootstrap method

Comment: I want to know if I can simply just use data.some_key in my .ts file to assign it to a var with the setup of import and module declaration in my question. I do not want to use provider and pipe.